# Parallel EventHandler

Tags: c#, events, parallel-processing, event-handling

I want to notify my class's event subscribers without delay and simultaneously.

Should I roll my own event handler; use some from FCL supporting parallelism; or default built-in `System.EventHandler<T>` support such way of event notification?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) for any delegate, and then just invoke all of the component delegates in parallel. That's probably the easiest way to go.

(It returns `Delegate[]` but you can cast each instance to the right type. You may even get away with casting the array itself - I can't remember exactly what kind of array it *actually* creates.)