# A way to raise an event so its subscribers run at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, events, asynchronous, .net-4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parallel EventHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302090/parallel-eventhandler)

If I have a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public void Fire() { if (Fired != null) Fired.Invoke(EventArgs.Empty); }
    public event EventHandler Fired;
}
```

And if I add multiple methods to the `Tested` event:

```
var foo= new Foo();
foo.Tested += FirstMethod;
foo.Tested += SecondMethod;
foo.Fire();
```

Is there something I can do to make the calls to `FirstMethod` and `SecondMethod` parallel?

Comment: dup. Side note: you can't guarantee that any pieces of code will run "at the same time" in any version of Windows as there is no way to control thread scheduling.

Comment: @Alexei: Thanks, but all I need is parallelism. So using GetInvocationList with Parallel.For is good enough for me.